# How to redirect only search engines?

Tags: php, redirect, web-crawler

I have a particular page where I want to redirect search engine spiders to another URL, but not normal users?

I was planning on using PHP 301 redirects to do the actual redirecting, but what is the best way to detect search engines?  IP address? User agent? Something else?

Comment: make your `robots.txt` file be a php script. most normal people don't hit that, so anyone hitting robots.txt can almost certainly be redirected.

Comment: robots.txt can contain redirects?

Comment: fetching it is an http request, which means the response header can contain a `Location:` header.

Comment: ok.  wouldn't expect that to work.  So, would you redirect to the new site's homepage, or the robots file on the new site?

Comment: well, if you want to redirect robots unconditionally, then use the robots.txt-as-php-script hack. for the one page, you'd be stuck looking at useragents and/or ips and then having `if(is_bot()) { redirect }`-type stuff.

Comment: The robots hack seems like it would work great.  I'm just trying to figure out whether it should redirect to the main page of the target site or the robots file of the target site.  Which is it?

Comment: @StackTracer, i want to know the same thing.  Can anyone confirm whether the redirect should point to the new site's homepage or if it should point to the new site's robots.txt file?